# Función para marcar, de varios elementos, solo uno cuando de un click en dicho elemento

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion para poner en `onMouseDown` y `onMouseUp` con React.js, y el problema es que tengo 12 elementos, y quiero que cuando aparezca el `onMouseDown` tenga un borde pero no a todos sino a el elemento que este clickeando y nose como hacerlo. He estado intentando hacerlo pero cuando doy click a un elemento se marcan todos. Si pudieran ayudarme con esto estaría genial :D.

codigo:

```js
    function Cards(props) {

    const onMouseDownCards = () => {
        let image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
        for(let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {                
                image[i].className = 'image img';
            }      
    };
    const onMouseUpCards = () => {
        let image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
        for(let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            image[i].classList = 'image';
        }
        
    };
    return (
  
        <div className='_cards' onMouseDown={onMouseDownCards} onMouseUp={onMouseUpCards} >
            <a className="cards" href='#'>
                <div className="image">
                    <span > { props.image } </span>
                </div>
            
                <div className="text">
                    <p> { props.description } </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        
    );
}
function ContainerCards() {
    return (
        <div className='container-cards' >
            <div className='main-cards-container'>
            { dataCuadro.map( ({ key, image, description}) => 
                <Cards key={key} image={image} description={description} />
            ) }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default ContainerCards;
```

Aqui sale cuando se mantiene un click
[image: asi se ve cuando mantengo el click]

Aqui cuando se suelta el click
[image: asi se ve cuando suelto el click]

Quiero que pase eso pero solo con el elemento que estoy dando click, no con todos, espero hacerme entender :(

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Hola, ya ubique el codigo e imagenes del output, espero que me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
const onMouseDownCards = (event) => {
    let image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        image[i].classList.remove('img');
    }
    event.target.classList.add('img');
};
const onMouseUpCards = () => {
    let image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        image[i].classList.remove('img');
    }
};
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).